# Button Click should invoke a tab pane (Dynamic) with text Panel inside

Tags: java, swing

I am looking for a example where upon click on different buttons should open different tab and the result/output should be written to the text panel inside it.

Text Panel should be embedded inside the tab.

And I am looking for Examples and not complete solution

Comment: Could you please be more specific? E.g. Do you want new tabs to be added upon button click or do you just want to change the active tab? Also, what exactly do you mean with 'result/output'?

Comment: @LuxxMiner I want new tab to be added upon button click and once the tab is added it should also trigger some method like which has some print statement and that should be redirected to inside the tab

Answer (score 1):

You should call `JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex` inside your button listener, try the following example :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main
{
    private static int numberOfTabs = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                        | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
                {
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 500);

                JButton addNewTab = new JButton("Add new Tab");

                JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();

                addNewTab.addActionListener(e -> {
                    tab.add(new JLabel("new tab " + numberOfTabs + " created."),
                            "tab " + numberOfTabs);
                    tab.setSelectedIndex(numberOfTabs - 1);
                    numberOfTabs++;
                });
                frame.add(addNewTab, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                frame.add(tab, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I want new tab to be added upon button click and once the tab is added it should also trigger some method like which has some print statement and that should be redirected to inside the tab

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Next thing which I was looking for that let say I have two buttons in the form panel and when I am clicking on that some output gets redirected to the tabs like if I click first button then output will go to the first tab and if I click second button then output will go to the second tab and both the tab have textarea inside it. Example appreciated

Comment: @user4021949 Show your try and i will help you to correct it.